# Aggregation in hierarchical tree

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

Need to do aggregation in hierarchical tree structure using Java, Please suggest some good methods or API to do this.

Tree Structure:

A is a root node and it has two nodes B and C.
B has two child nodes B1 and B2 and similarly C has two child nodes C1 and C2. Each leaf node has some value associated.

I need to aggregate values starting from leaf to all the way root node.

In above example, if the values of leaf nodes are B1=5, B2=5, C1=3 and C2=7. Then Aggregation would give value 10 to B node and 10 to C node. Root node A will have value 20.

Please suggest solution.

I have to load the tree structure from file. My file is like below.

Node|Id|ParentId
A|1|1
B|2|1
C|3|1
B1|4|2
B2|5|2
C1|6|3
C2|7|3

Comment: you should try it using linkedlist

Comment: I have not implemented anything yet. I am thinking to have a data structure which i can traverse from leaf node to root node and aggregate value at each parent node.

Comment: Prashant, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest investigating the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). Essentially this involves having an interface `Node` with method `getValue` and then implementations of `Node` called `Leaf` and `Composite`. The composite has references to `Node`.

The different implementations of `getValue` either return the leaf value or sum up the values of children.

For example:

```
interface Node {
    public int getValue();
}

class Leaf implements Node {
    private final int value;
    public Leaf(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

class Composite implements Node {
    private final Node left;
    private final Node right;
    public Composite(Node left, Node right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    public int getValue() {
        return left.getValue() + right.getValue();
    }
}
```

Here's example code using this hierarchy:

```
Leaf b1 = new Leaf(5);
Leaf b2 = new Leaf(5);
Node b = new Node(b1, b2);
Leaf c1 = new Leaf(3);
Leaf c2 = new Leaf(7);
Node c = new Node(c1, c2);
Node a = new Node(b, c);
System.out.println("a value = " + a.getValue());
```

When you call a.getValue() it calls b.getValue() which calls b1.getValue() and so on. The tree is traversed and values are summed.

As requested in the comments, constructors added - though I feel suspicious that I'm doing your assignment for you!

Comment: I have to treat each node individually not as a composition of other nodes. How composition can help me to traverse from leaf node to root?

Comment: I'll add some sample code to the answer so it is clearer.

Comment: Thanks Sprinter for the sample code. This is a static design structure. I have to create tree dynamically. At run time, i would come to know about my nodes and its parent/child. At run time, how do i create this structure and do aggregation?

Comment: I just added the file sample above. Using this file, i have to create tree structure in memory.

Comment: I've explained aggregation. Creating the constructors really should be trivial if you know Java. Do you really need me to show you how to construct the tree?

Comment: At least accept my answer please :-)

Comment: Done. :-)
However, i described only 50% of my problem here...will create another q for this. Pls find the line below.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893810/aggregation-of-cartesian-product-of-two-hierachical-trees-using-java