# Aggregation of cartesian product of two hierachical trees using Java

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, hierarchical-data, cartesian-product

Need to do aggregation of Cartesian product of two hierarchical tree structures using Java, Please suggest some good methods or API to do this.

Tree Structure:

Country Tree :

Node|Id|ParentId

World|1|1 
Asia|2|1
Europe|3|1
India|4|2
China|5|2
UK|6|3
Hungary|7|3
Cyprus|8|3

Profit Tree:

Node|Id|ParentId
Profit|1|1
Revenue|2|1
Expense|3|1

Cartesian product of these two products would give me 24 combinations (8 X 3). I need to aggregate values for each of the combination.

For example, I want to know Total revenue of Europe, Asia and World, Total Profit of Europe etc

Comment: You have provided the data for the two trees but you haven't really provided the structures. Can you post your definitions for the two trees? It's hard to suggest code to aggregate without the definitions.

Comment: Why do you have IDs for each of the nodes? Is that just incoming data that can later be ignored?

Comment: What is the relationship between the two trees? Do the country leaf nodes have profit nodes as children?

Comment: Two trees are independent.
IDs of each node is there so a node can become parent of other nodes. Please see the data set.

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't make a lot of sense to me. There must be something linking the two sets of data or you can't possibly get the data for a node. The IDs might be required when you read the data in but in Java they will be linked via references, not IDs.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to answer without details of the structures. But I'll guess what they might be and you can extrapolate to your structures.

```
enum EconomicDataType {
    PROFIT, REVENUE, EXPENSE;
}

interface GeographicNode {
    int getEconomicData(EconomicDataType type);
}

class Region implements GeographicNode {
    private List<GeographicNode> geographiesInRegion;
    public int getEconomicData(EconomicDataType type) {
        return geographiesInRegion.stream()
            .mapToInt(geog -> geog.getEconomicData(type))
            .sum();
    }
}

class Country implements GeographicNode {
    private EnumMap<GeographicNode, Integer> economicData;
    public int getEconomicData(EconomicDataType type) {
        return economicData.get(type);
    }
}
```

I have modelled economic data as a map rather than a tree because, frankly, it makes no sense to me to make it a hierarchy given there's nothing hierarchical about the data.

I also haven't handled the situation in which data is missing. Not hard to add with a `containsKey` check before getting the data from the map.

Retrieving someing like total revenue for europe is:

```
europe.getEconomicData(EconomicDataType.REVENUE);
```

Simple :-)

Comment: I think you didn't get the question. Two trees are independent and they are big like 10 to 20 levels with many leaf nodes. Can you provide the solution which can work for any number of nodes ?
In reality, my Cartesian product gives me 200K different combinations.

Comment: This solution will work for any number of nodes. The Region class contains a list of Nodes which can themselves be regions or countries. It can go as deep as you want.

Comment: You have defined second tree as Enum. how can it be tree?

Comment: It's not a tree (or an enum) but a map. I said in the answer that I couldn't imagine how you could represent the data hierarchically so I didn't bother trying. What does it mean for revenue data to be the child of other revenue data?

Comment: Ah ok I think I see what this means now - profit is the parent of revenue and expenses. In other words profit is calculated as revenue - expense but each of those are also available. Is that what you mean? If that's the case then it's not really a tree - you only have 2 levels with profit referencing expense and revenue.

Comment: If you can confirm that assumption I could give some further hints.

Comment: There is no relationship between Profile and Loss. They are just two different things to calculate Profile. They make more sense when they are associated with geography tree. In data file, what i get is like India and its revenue, china with its revenue. You see there is  a relation between two trees here.. For ex, For Asia what is my profit then i would aggregate India and China revenue...I hope you understand now...

Comment: No you still haven't explained why profit, loss and expenses are in a tree structure. I can see why they would be associated with nodes in the geography tree but I can't see why they would be a separate tree structure themselves.

Comment: Please dont go by the names. Its a tree which is associated with other tree. In reality, i would love to call you up to explain the problem :-)

Comment: I'm sorry but that makes no sense at all. I'll post code that would represent a 'tree associated with the other tree' and you'll see that it's not close to what you are asking her.

Comment: I need to represent example in other way...let me prepare and edit the earlier example...give me few mins...

Comment: Actually I started to post the code but it made the answer unintelligible. You'll have to explain what you mean.